# Как получить имя css?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нигде не могу найти как узнать имя `css`.

Например отсюда:

```
<div class="item item-2" id='lost'><div>

<script> $('#lost'). //как дописать, чтобы получить название class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так название класса целиком

```
document.getElementById('lost').className
```

Так название класса в массиве

```
document.getElementById('lost').classList
```

Answer (score 7):

```js
console.log($('#lost').attr('class'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item item-2" id='lost'><div>
```